# Apache interface except localhost not working

Tags: macos, apache, virtualhost

So I am on Mac and installed apache, php etc. using homebrew. In my `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` I have `Listen 80`. I can access documentroot via `http://localhost` but not via `http://192.168.1.6` (this is my local IP) or `http://127.0.0.1`. The latter 2 URLs leads to show forbidden error - http://puu.sh/3dTkb.png

Can someone help me with this ? Been stuck for hours now!

Answer (score 0):

Actually this all are same only.you try with your port number apache default portnumber is 8080 .. so url look like this `http://192.168.1.6:8080/yourapplication or document` check your port number

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/urapp
```

u can use this also .

Comment: apache is running on port 80, not 8080

Comment: http://192.168.1.6:80 after you given this also it working?. wat error or wat else problem is coming.